# Extract CSS media queries from websites with python 2.7

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, csv, web-crawler

I'm trying to find a specific CSS media query (`@media only screen`) in **CSS files** of websites by using a crawler in python 2.7.

Right now I can crawl websites/URLs (from a CSV file) to find specific keywords in their **HTML source code** using the following code:

```
import urllib2

keyword = ['keyword to find']

with open('listofURLs.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        if strdomain:
            req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            html_content = response.read()

            for searchstring in keyword:
                if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
                    print (strdomain, keyword, 'found')
f.close()
```

However, I now would like to crawl websites/ULRs (from the CSV file) to find the `@media only screen` query in their CSS files/source code. How should my code look like?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to:

1° read the csv file and put each url in a Python list;

2° loop this list, go to the pages and extract the list of css links. You need an HTML parser, for example BeautifulSoup;

3° browse the list of links and extract the item you need. There are CSS parsers like tinycss or cssutils, but I've never used them. A regex can maybe do the trick, even if this is probably not recommended.

4° write the results

Since you know how to read the csv (PS : no need to close the file with `f.close()` when you use the `with open` method), here is a minimal suggestion for operations 2 and 3. Feel free to adapt it to your needs and to improve it. I used Python 3, but I think it works on Python 2.7.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = ["https://76crimes.com/2014/06/25/zambia-to-west-dont-watch-when-we-jail-lgbt-people/"]

for url in url_list:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        css_links = [link["href"] for link in soup.findAll("link") if "stylesheet" in link.get("rel", [])]
        print(css_links)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, url)
        pass

css_links = ["https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=d9243128ba1c"]

#your regular expression
pattern = re.compile(r'@media only screen.+?\}')

for url in css_links:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url).text
        media_only = pattern.findall(response)
        print(media_only)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, url)
        pass
```